# generated texture displacement adds a line to the displacement

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement

I'm trying to add displacement to an object via generated textures in cycles. For some reason it adds this line across my objects. If I view the texture on the surface it looks fine (see 2nd screenshot). The moment i use a diffuse color on the surface the line shows up. I've tried adding a "normal" node as well as displacement node. I can't make the line go away. Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are presumably using a Blender version greater than 2.79b - eg, 2.79.5 - where the Displacement socket is now a vector rather than a scalar value (blue rather than gray). You need to add a Displacement node before the Displacement socket to convert the ‘height’ from your texture into a vector along the normal of the surface, rather than interpreting it as a vector in world space.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I am trying to use the latest builds of blender 2.79. If I add a "vector displacement node" and keep it set to "tangent space", the line goes away. If I use "object space" or "world space", the line reappears. It gives me a work around. Thanks again!